# Node for BST in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm having some trouble with writing a node for my Binary Search Tree. I know it should point to the left child and right child, and in the data field it will have a string, but I also want it to point to an arraylist. Which is the part I'm not sure how to code myself in java.

```
class BSTNode {

    BSTNode( Comparable theString ) {
        element = theString;
        left = right = null;
    }

    Comparable element;      // The data in the node
    BSTNode left;         // Left child
    BSTNode right;        // Right child
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far? (And what is the purpose of the `ArrayList`? I don't believe that's a part of a standard binary search tree)

Comment: Show you current code, please!

Comment: You can represent a binary search tree in an array.

Comment: I want to use an arraylist to keep track of the files that contain a certain word.

Comment: So you want an `ArrayList` to be associated with each node in the same way that a string will be associated with each node? It is a little unclear exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I want a node to hold a string and an arraylist of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To also have an `ArrayList<String>` at each node, you simply add an `ArrayList<String>` field to the node class like this:

```
public class BSTNode {
    private String value;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfStrings;
    private BSTNode left;
    private BSTNode right;

    // Constructor and other methods here

}
```

Then, on top of the normal BST methods, you will probably want to add accessor and mutator methods for your `ArrayList<String>` field. How that is done obviously depends on what you intend to do with the tree.

Here's an example of a simple method to add a string to the `ArrayList<String>`:

```
 public void addStringToList(String str) {
   this.listOfStrings.add(str);
 }
```

An example of a method to get the whole `ArrayList<String>`:

```
 public ArrayList<String> getList() {
   return this.listOfStrings;
 }
```

These methods would go right in the body of the BSTNode class.

If I didn't answer your question, consider editing your question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. My issue is with the accessor and mutator methods, I'm not sure how I can just simply add a string to the arraylist of the node.

Comment: Hmm I get a NullPointerException at the addStringToList method.

Comment: It is probably because you have not initialized `listOfStrings`. You should initialize it in your BSTNode constructor.

Comment: private ArrayList listOfStrings = new ArrayList();